# Run Apache Jmeter though command line and generate "view result tree" file

Tags: apache, jmeter

I'm running apache jmeter 3.3 on centos command line and generating ".jtl" Summary Report file using following command

```
./jmeter -n -t requests.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Can I generate some file and view result tree by importing file to apache jmeter GUI. If yes , then how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, just add a View Result Tree to your test and fill in the filename field:

[image: View Results Tree]

Ensure you check the fields you want by clicking on "Configure":

[image: Configure]

Note that the more you save things the more you impact performances of JMeter

Answer (score 1):

You can run your test as:

```
./jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t requests.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Alternatively you can add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

This way JMeter will store results in a way they could be examined in the View Results Tree listener.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)